# Why Powershell method not calling second time

Tags: powershell

In the below code ShowVirtualDetails extracting the members(10.244.61.156:53,10.244.61.186:53) from JSON object and returning the result and also displaying virtual information.

Issue:

1. virtual information not displaying twice
2. If I use ExistedIps in another method, it contains some garbage values as well Ex: System.Object System.Object System.Object 10.244.61.156:53, 10.244.61.186:53 why System.Object prepending at the begin.

**Implementation:**

```
Function ShowVirtualDetails($Virtual, $OutputPath)
{
    "calling"
    $Result = @"
{"VirtualMembersStatus":[{"VirtualName":"xxx_T01","AllowableVlans":null,"LoadBalanceMethod":null,"Pools":["xxx_sg_test01"],"Members":{"10.244.61.156:53":"ENABLED","10.244.61.186:53":"ENABLED"},"MonitorName":null,"Policies":null,"SnatPoolName":null,"VirtualEndPoint":"10.20.4.187:53","VirtualType":null,"Profiles":null,"Protocol":null}],"ANPError":{"ID":"eb888cfc-d685-4ae7-a778-fe0cc4cc88a1","CorrelationID":"8157f735-f807-4a36-a112-8a01ec4ee837","Code":{"Vyalue":"HWP1"},"Name":"NoFault","Arguments":["Unknown"],"Message":"Unknown","Description":"\"No Fault\"","RoutingGuide":{"RoutingAction":0,"OwningTeam":null,"RoutingId":null,"Retriable":false}},"QueriedInstance":"PN1PPFCF7DD500C","Succeeded":true,"Errors":{"TerminatingFaultCode":"NoFault","TerminatingFaultMessage":null,"Capacity":4,"Count":1},"EventGuid":"xxxxx","BaseReturnValue":null}
"@
    $Data = $Result | convertFrom-json
    $existed_Ips = @()
    if ($Data.VirtualMembersStatus -ne $null)
    {
        $temp = $Data.VirtualMembersStatus.Members
        $res = $Data.VirtualMembersStatus | convertto-json -depth 100
        Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "`t`t$Virtual Details"  -PassThru 
        Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" -PassThru 
        Add-Content -Path $OutputPath -Value $res -PassThru     
        $existed_Ips = $temp.PSObject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object { $_ }       
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Activity ID:" $Result.ActivityId -ForegroundColor Red        
    }
    return $existed_Ips
}
$OutputPath = ".\Logs\output.txt"
New-Item -Path $OutputPath -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
$Script:ExistedIps = ShowVirtualDetails "v1" $OutputPath
$Script:ExistedIps2 = ShowVirtualDetails "v3" $OutputPath
$ExistedIps
```

Result:

```
calling
                v1 Details
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        "VirtualName":  "xxx_T01",
        "AllowableVlans":  null,
        "LoadBalanceMethod":  null,
        "Pools":  [
                      "xxx_sg_test01"
                  ],
        "Members":  {
                        "10.244.61.156:53":  "ENABLED",
                        "10.244.61.186:53":  "ENABLED"
                    },
        "MonitorName":  null,
        "Policies":  null,
        "SnatPoolName":  null,
        "VirtualEndPoint":  "10.20.4.187:53",
        "VirtualType":  null,
        "Profiles":  null,
        "Protocol":  null
    }
    10.244.61.156:53
    10.244.61.186:53
```

Comment: If I use ```$ExistedIps;
'---';
$ExistedIps2;
'===';
Get-Content -Path $OutputPath;
``` instead of final output command `$ExistedIps` then all looks O.K. …

Comment: Note that  `$ExistedIps.Count` returns `6` - are you expecting `2`? Run `$ExistedIps| ForEach-Object { $_.GetType().FullName; $_}` to see what happened. Deleting `PassThru`  from _all_ `Add-Content` gets a bit better output (count = `3` now, with the string `calling` at index `0`). Read [about_Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) to see why: _In PowerShell, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword_…